# Los tipos de datos varchar y xml son incompatibles con el operador add

Tags: sql

en un SP estoy concatenando un valor en una variable xml que recibo, como puedo concatenar mi valor pero respetando que el tipo sea xml? ya que si lo hago unicamente con el signo + me dice que

> Los tipos de datos varchar y xml son incompatibles con el operador
> add.

```html
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Clientes](
    @TipoReporte smallint,
    @CompaniasXml xml
    )
AS
Begin

  declare @XMLcompanias as xml
  set @XMLcompanias='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso8859-1"?>'+@CompaniasXml
  select @XMLcompanias
  End
```

Answer (score 0):

Los XML son entidades, en teoría no puedes simplemente concatenar 2 archivos porque la estructura quedaría comprometida.

Para solucionar eso, es necesario convertir el XML a cadena de texto y luego convertir todo a XML de nuevo. Claro, suponiendo que eso no afectará la estructura del XML y falle la conversión. Para evitar errores puedes usar bloques `TRY...CATCH...` o la función `TRY_CONVERT()`.

```
set @XMLcompanias=TRY_CONVERT( XML, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso8859-1"?>'+CAST( @CompaniasXml as varchar(MAX)))
```